# How to Check null for double type of value in java

Tags: java

I have A double type of variable. I want to check whether the variable is null or not. I read that double will never become null, They suggested me to change datatype double to Double. If I change double to Double I am Having performance issue.Here I need to check null pointer.

```
double dbl=ParentBean.getChildBean().getDays();
```

How to check `dbl` is null or not.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: dbl can not be null, because it is a primitiv type

Comment: yes I will accept with you. but is there any alternate

Comment: It sounds like now your actual problem is performance problems, but you haven't told us anything about those...

Comment: if method getDays() 's return type is double (not Double), then return values from getDays must not be null. because double is a primitive type.

Comment: Explain about the performance issue. What kind of performance issue? The only thing that can be null is an object, so you'll need to use some kind of object. If you show your code and explain where you see performance problems, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

** Default value for Primitive double is always 0.0d
ref: http://www.c4learn.com/java/java-default-values/

so do not expect null in it

Answer (score 0):

You can check null for wrapper class of double.

Change the double to it's wrapper class [Double](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) and check with == for null.

```
Double dbl=ParentBean.getChildBean().getDays();
```

Now you can do:-

```
if(dbl==null)
```

or you can do something like below, if getDays() return type is Double:-

```
double dbl=ParentBean.getChildBean().getDays()==null?0.00d:ParentBean.getChildBean().getDays();
```

Above statement I am checking for null, if true assigning sentinel value -1d to double dbl else ParentBean.getChildBean().getDays().
Assigning sentinel value is not right approach but.

Comment: `dbl` will **never** be `null` if the return type of `getDays()` is actually `double` rather than `Double`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, true, but if that's the case, then his question is invalid. I am assuming that getDays() may return null in some cases .

Answer (score 0):

you can not check a primitive (`double`, `float`, `long`, `int`, `char`, `short`, `byte`, `boolean`) datatype for `null`.

primitives have a value always. you can only check references to Objects for null. there is a wrapper Object for each of the primitives (`Double`, `Float`, `Long`, `Integer`, ...) if you use these, then you can check for null.

**Example:**

```
double c = 2.16;
Double d = new Double(c);
if(d != null){
     System.out.println("not null double variable");
}
```